# Safety of white canned beans

Tags: food-safety

What is the slight pink color on white canned beans?  I am concerned they may have spoiled and I should not use them.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the accepted answer of [this Seasoned Advice question (Are these worms in my black eyed peas/beans?):](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35244/are-these-worms-in-my-black-eyed-peas-beans)

> Beans and related plants have an embryo in their seeds. In white legumes, the embryo is a light pink color and looks indeed like a larva.

That's likely what you're seeing. I know I've used white beans that were pink-ish before, and nothing bad has ever happened (though I'm hardly an authoritative source). Biggest thing to check for in canned beans, as far as I know, is whether the can itself is swollen at all, and whether the beans/juice have an unusual smell.

Comment: +1 for: check for swollen can or unusual odor. Also, if the OP has experience with this variety of beans, and this batch seems "off" in color or other characteristics, I might not use them. But if the OP doesn't have a lot of experience with these beans, it's tough to know whether they are bad or not just from this brief description.