# Just found this in my donner kebab, can you identify what it is?

Tags: food-safety, kebab

I was just eating a donner kebab, not sure if it’s something to be alarmed about ( looks like a worm to me ) or if it’s just spice that is tricking me.

It’s about 2/3mm across and is very hard. I can’t see anything moving... yet [grin]

Thank you for your help in advance, hopefully this is in-topic :) [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you are looking at a capsicum seed. In other words, you either had a piece of jalapeño, pickled pepperoni, or a sprinkle of [pul biber (crushed red pepper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crushed_red_pepper). They are flat, about 2mm wide with that little tip.

The “worm” is actually the embryonic part of the seed. There are a few edible seeds which seem to have a “worm”, e.g. [this Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35244/are-these-worms-in-my-black-eyed-peas-beans) on our site.

Comment: I personally would be miffed if I couldn’t find any - then my doner seller would have skimped on the spice.